# How to correctly scale custom thumb for a switch widget?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've a custom thumb set from a drawable for a `Switch` widget inside a `LinearLayout`. I can't get it to show correctly on all kinds of screens. On most screens, it looks like this-

[image: correct]

Which is fine, but on some screens (example - 440 dpi), it'd look like this-

[image: wrong]

How do I get this to look uniform across all screens? I've tried many things, including `switchMinWidth`, setting `android:width=` to 0dp, using `thumbTextPadding` but nothing works. Everything has the *exact* same result, it works on some screens but not on others.

Here's my `Switch` widget placed inside a `LinearLayout` with a `layout_weight` of 2. There are *usually* 5 widgets in each Horizontal `LinearLayout` but this specific one has 4 as `Switch` is supposed to take 2 slots.

```xml
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/btndegreerad"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/degree_rad_track"
            android:showText="true"
            android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextTheme"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textOff="@string/btnrad"
            android:textOn="@string/btndegree"
            android:thumb="@drawable/degree_rad_thumb"
            android:thumbTextPadding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:thumbTint="@color/colorSwitch"
            android:track="@drawable/degree_rad_track" />
```

Here's the `degree_rad_thumb` drawable-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="@dimen/_38sdp" android:width="0dp"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="@dimen/_38sdp" android:width="0dp"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here's also `degree_rad_track`, though this is probably not needed-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorFadedPrimary"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorFadedPrimary"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Try to replace all of your `dp` dimensions to `sdp`. check [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: I already have pretty much everything set to `sdp`. If you meant I should change the `Radius` to `sdp` as well, well it doesn't make any difference, I tried.

Comment: The main issue i can find is you are limiting the width of switch using weight, while the thumb has to wrap the whole content "radian"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to correctly scale to all screens on anything; My best rules are using ScrollView and RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout in general so it's usable and scales.

You can choose between ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout; Both should scale correctly, perhaps Relative is easier since you don't have to set the constraints. ScrollView isn't necessarily needed here since we don't have a lot of data.

Try putting your Switch inside a RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout and it should work.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/btndegreerad"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/degree_rad_track"
                    android:showText="true"
                    android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextTheme"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:textOff="@string/btnrad"
                    android:textOn="@string/btndegree"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/degree_rad_thumb"
                    android:thumbTextPadding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:thumbTint="@color/colorSwitch"
                    android:track="@drawable/degree_rad_track" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Note: Customise the layouts as you want

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. Just for future reference, could you also edit to mention that this will work with `ConstraintLayout` as well? That's what I ended up using instead of `RelativeLayout` but both should work
Also, move `layout_weight` to the outer layout instead of `switch`

Comment: Hi! I'm glad it worked. Ah sorry about that, I edited my answer to tell it works with other layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a similar layout using Switch with custom drawable for its thumb and track. From what I have learned, LinearLayout weight property can affect your Switch track's drawable (either cropped or squished) if your device width doesn't provide enough room.

With this unwanted behavior, I recommend changing your layout type to [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#ConstraintLayout) if you really need to get your custom drawable working on different screen sizes. This solution is also recommended in this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

But if you really want to use LinearLayout, don't use `layout_weight` for your Switch.

Comment: So there's no way to do it with a layout weight in linear layout?

Comment: Sadly there is no other way. LinearLayout `layout_weight` cannot perfectly scale down views without cropping/squishing it if there is not enough space.